# Similarity matrix in clustering

Tags: data-mining, clustering, similarity

I am coding an algorithm for clustering that is explained in [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7f2CpH4zpJIbjlGbmFyMDNNUWM) paper. According to the paper, the algorithm clusters by structural similarity and attribute similarity.

In clustering with attribute similarity, I have problem. I believe that it says, first, to cluster with structural similarity and then partition the cluster with attribute similarity between the vertex. However, I can't understand how to find the attribute similarity between the vertex in a cluster.

The algorithm is described [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7f2CpH4zpJIbjlGbmFyMDNNUWM) on page 4.

Answer (score 2):

A *vertex* (the same as: *node*) is a word used in [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) to denote an object. Also: an *edge* joining two *vertices*, denotes a relation between objects.

So, in this case, a similarity between objects A and B is the weight of an edge joining vertices corresponding to those objects.

Comment: thank you for your answer but in this paper we don`t need  weight of an edge. I need attribute similarity in this paper because every vertex have some attribute like sex(f/m),eye color or ..... in this paper use similarity matrix for this.

Comment: In the paper you supplied, the similarity with respect to attribute a between vertex i and vertex j is defined in line 294 (page 4) as: 1, if vertices i and j have the same value of attribute a, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: thank you but i have another problem when i clustering the vertex i should cluster the vertex in a cluster by attribute or i should cluster all vertex by attribute again?

Comment: Well, it depends on what kind of similarity between objects *you* are interested in. The way I see it, clustering can help you find unknown (and often surprising) patterns in your data, but only if you use a meaningful similarity function between objects (i.e.: *you* know what it means that two objects are similar).